# Location Exception while using GPS(Location API)

Tags: java, java-me, geolocation

I have downloaded google map application on sonyerricsom T700 mobile its working fine,its java application.So as per my understanding that is also using Location API.
This [link](http://www.gsmarena.com/sony_ericsson_t700-2481.php) shows that it does not have GPS.
But it is showing map and even locating photo's clicked on device on google map.

So I am tried below code in j2me using Location API(JSR-179).Its working fine on emulator.
But when I am trying the same on Sony erisccon T700 mobile its giving below exception:

Exception:

```
javax.microedition.location.LocationException:All service providers are out of service.
```

Code:

```
try {

// Create a Criteria object for defining desired selection criteria
Criteria cr = new Criteria();
LocationProvider lp = LocationProvider.getInstance(cr);    
l = lp.getLocation(60);    
c = l.getQualifiedCoordinates();    
//cityMap.setCategories(selectedCategories);
if (c != null) {
// use coordinate information
double lat = c.getLatitude();    
//latitude="";
latitude = ""+lat;
Latitude.setString(latitude);
double lon = c.getLongitude();
longitude =""+lon;
Longitude.setString(longitude);
}
}
catch (LocationException e) {
alert = new Alert("LocationException");
alert.setString("Unable to retrive location information:" + e);
alert.setTimeout(2000);
display.setCurrent(alert);
// not able to retrive location information
//e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
alert = new Alert("InterruptedException");
alert.setString("Operation Interrupted:" + ie);
alert.setTimeout(2000);
display.setCurrent(alert);    
}    
}
```

Please suggest me any solution for this...

Thank and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I bet it's not *exact* location like you would get from GPS.

Google has other ways of finding your location...  it's probably using Cell ID.  Luckily Sony Ericsson  handsets are quite easy to find Cell ID from, see [here](http://www.paxmodept.com/telesto/blogitem.htm?id=381).  Once you have it, you can look it up in a [cell ID database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82184/public-cell-id-databases) to find location.

Comment: yes it is not giving exact location as in GPS.it is just showing the city in the map.then how can i get log lat of the device.And i want to do it generally that is for nokia ,samsung,LG etc .Please help me.Thanks for the reply

Comment: I've already explained how you can do it for Sony Ericsson using cell ID.  Unfortunately there is no generic method for getting this from all handsets.